# "Aussi étonnamment que" est-il correct ?

Tags: formulation

> Aussi **étonnamment** que tristement, s'intéresser à cette chose n'intéressait personne

Est-ce correct ?

Comment: Le plus douteux c'est peut-être de savoir si  « s'intéresser » peut intéresser, mais a priori ça ne choque pas trop. C'est quand même une question intéressante…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cette phrase est correcte, et elle le reste avec un synonyme (pris dans son sens littéraire) qui renforce l'idée qu'il n'y a que le locuteur qui s'intéresse *à cette chose*, mais ce mot élimine la *surprise*, l'*étonnement* de cette découverte, et pourrait être aussi remplacé par *bizarrement* :

> Aussi **singulièrement** que tristement, s'intéresser à cette chose n'intéressait personne.

Comment: Merci ! Quand tu dis "il" ("il élimine la surprise de cette découverte") "Il"c'est quoi ? Ce sont les synonymes que tu proposes (bizarrement, singulièrement )   ?

Comment: @GuillaumeCombot J'ai levé l’ambiguïté, il faut lire *ce mot*.